# mongodb native driver error on query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am writing the filter using mongodb native driver, but it's driving me this error when you run the query.

In the case of this driver, it has no exec?

What is another way to perform this query?

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

        var section     = req.params.section;
        var collection  = db.collection(section);

        var filter = req.query.filter ? {nameToLower: new RegExp('^' + req.query.filter.toLowerCase())} : {};
        var query = collection.find(filter);
        var count = 0;

        collection.count(filter, function (error, result) {
            count = result;
        });

        if(req.query.order) {
            query.sort(req.query.order);
        }

        if(req.query.limit) {
            query.limit(req.query.limit);

            if(req.query.page) {
                query.skip(req.query.limit * --req.query.page);
            }
        }

        query.exec(function (error, results) {
            res.json({
                count: count,
                data: results
            });
        });

    });

};
```

Error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific on the Error. **On which line did it indicate an error?**

Comment: query.exec(function (error, results) {
            res.json({
                count: count,
                data: results
            });
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library in this case as it simplifies the code. In the case where you need to run multiple tasks that depend on each other and when they all finish do something else, use the 
**[`async.series()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback)** module. The following demonstrates how you can go about this in your case:

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
    var locals = {},
        section = req.params.section,
        filter = !!req.query.filter ? {nameToLower: new RegExp('^' + req.query.filter.toLowerCase())} : {};
    async.series([
        // Connect to DB
        function(callback) {
            MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
                if (err) return callback(err);              
                locals.collection = db.collection(section); //Set the collection here, so the next task can access it
                callback();
            });
        },
        // Get count
        function(callback) {
            locals.collection.count(filter, function (err, result){
                if (err) return callback(err);              
                locals.count = result; //Set the count here
                callback();
            });         
        },      
        // Query collection
        function(callback) {
            var cursor = locals.collection.find(filter);
            if(req.query.order) {
                cursor = cursor.sort(req.query.order);
            }

            if(req.query.limit) {
                cursor = cursor.limit(req.query.limit);

                if(req.query.page) {
                    cursor = cursor.skip(req.query.limit * --req.query.page);
                }
            }
            cursor.toArray(function(err, docs) {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                locals.docs = docs;
                callback();
            });
        }
    ], function(err) { //This function gets called after the three tasks have called their "task callbacks"
        if (err) return next(err);
        // Here locals will be populated with 'count' and 'docs'
        res.json({
            count: locals.count,
            data: locals.docs
        });
        res.render('user-profile', locals);
    });
};
```

Comment: very good, To send the filters to find, return me an error: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue sort must be object or array